# Multiply each subsequent second column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to multiply the first columns with the first and with the third columns. Below you can see my data.

```
  df<-data.frame(  
  Stores=c(10,10,20,0,10),
  Value1=c(10,10,0,100,0),
  Value2=c(10,10,0,100,0),
  Value3=c(10,0,0,0,0),
  Value4=c(10,10,0,0,0)
  )

df
```

Now I want to multiply the first column `Stores` with each subsequent second column or in this case `Value2` and `Value4.`

[image]

I tried to do this with mutate but I think that I am not in the right way because, in reality, I need to apply this on large data sets with around 50 columns.

```
df<-mutate(df,
           solved1=Stores*Value2)
```

So can anybody help me with how to solve this in an automatic way?

Comment: `df[,1] * df[seq(3,ncol(df), by = 2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R solution, building on @onyambu’s comment:

```
new <- df[,1] * df[seq(3, ncol(df), by = 2)]
colnames(new) <- paste0("solved", seq_along(new))
df <- cbind(df, new)
df
```

```
  Stores Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 solved1 solved2
1     10     10     10     10     10     100     100
2     10     10     10      0     10     100     100
3     20      0      0      0      0       0       0
4      0    100    100      0      0       0       0
5     10      0      0      0      0       0       0
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from akrun's pure tidyverse solution (which is preferable), we could use `dplyover::over()` for this kind of operations (disclaimer: I'm, the maintainer, and the package is not on CRAN).

We can create a sequence to loop over, below `seq(2, 4, 2)` running from `2` to `4` and then we can construct the variable names inside `.()`, below  `.("Value{.x}")`, so in each iteration we loop over one of the values of our sequence (below: `Value2` and `Value4`).

Finally, we need nice output names. Here we can set the `.names` argument to `"solved{x_idx}"`  which says "take the string `"solved"` and append to it the index of the current iteration `{x_idx}`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/

df %>% 
  mutate(over(seq(2, 4, 2),
              ~ Stores * .("Value{.x}"),
              .names = "solved{x_idx}"
              )
         )
#>   Stores Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 solved1 solved2
#> 1     10     10     10     10     10     100     100
#> 2     10     10     10      0     10     100     100
#> 3     20      0      0      0      0       0       0
#> 4      0    100    100      0      0       0       0
#> 5     10      0      0      0      0       0       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, please check

```r
# get the names of the columns to multiply
nam <- names(df)[which(str_detect(names(df),'^Val.*[2|4]$'))]

# use the nam vector with elements as variable names 
df %>% mutate(across(nam, ~Stores*.x, .names = 'solved{col}')) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~ str_replace_all(.x,'Value',''))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  Stores   1   2  3  4 solved2 solved4
1     10  10  10 10 10     100     100
2     10  10  10  0 10     100     100
3     20   0   0  0  0       0       0
4      0 100 100  0  0       0       0
5     10   0   0  0  0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `across` in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(names(.)[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)]), ~ .x * Stores,
        .names = "Solved{str_remove(.col, 'Value')}"))
```